# How to take HTML with Jsoup?

Tags: html, web-scraping, jsoup

How to get all HTML of site like this: https://www.ranker.com/crowdranked-list/the-best-movies-of-all-time

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

This code gives me only first part of loaded films (from 1st to 25th place).
How to get all of them which are show after scrolling down?

Comment: you should scrape using `https://cache-api.ranker.com/lists/298553/items?limit=25&offset=50&include=votes,wikiText,rankings,openListItemContributors&propertyFetchType=ALL&liCacheKey=db8ad90a-0f39-4f62-a357-e84438eb7da3` URL's

Comment: How to get this from other sites?

Comment: dig in their code and find the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the first 25 are *in* the HTML in the first place. Later ones are dynamically added to the page using JavaScript.

If you want the others then you'll either need to replace Jsoup with a tool that will execute JavaScript, or you'll need to reverse engineer the JavaScript and replicate what it does.